# Fill double array with random numbers and then print even and odd numbers from that array

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers, double

So here's my problem. I have to write a program that will fill array with random numbers(and it's ok), then it's necessary to print only even index numbers or only odd value numbers(`j`). Tried like this but when i put `if` statement and it shows every even number (index and value-the second in array) so it wrong. What should i do so?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Array {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int rows = 5;
    int colu = 2;
    
    Random r = new Random();
    
    int [][] array = new int [rows][colu];
    
    for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++)
        {
            array[row][col] = r.nextInt(10);
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {       
        for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(array[i][j]%2 == 0){
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }

            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

[image: How it should like]

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean wrong? Can you give us an example array that should work but doesn't?

Comment: I don't get it.  You complain that "it shows every even number", but I thought that's what you want.

Comment: @sdasdadas "If" statement have to search even numbers in the first place in array("i" here), antoher "if" must be looking for odd numbers in second place in array("j" in this case)

Comment: @Hot Licks Yes, i mean that it shows all even numbers from "i" and "j" too. And it has to show only from "i", then show odd numbers in "j"

Comment: Imagine your double array as a square with rows and columns (as your code already dictates). Each slot in the square is filled with random integer values. Now assume you run some secret code (which we'll figure out soon) on the square. What values are left? Can you show us what a square looks like before and after you run your code? That would help a lot in understanding what you need.

Comment: > to print only even index numbers or only odd value numbers(j)
If I get it correctly, you mean this?

if(i%2==0 || j%2 != 0) {
  print array[i][j];
}

Comment: "i" is addressing a sub-array.  "j" addresses an element in that sub-array.  It's meaningless to say you want only the "i" elements or only the "j" elements.

Comment: @sdasdadas file attached

Comment: @UsmanSaleem I checked, doesn't work. And for sure, it doesn't need to show all of this at one step. If you want to show only even numbers from first column you can mark the odd numbers from second column as a comment.

Comment: @Fastkowy you wish array indexing to be odd or even, or the values to be odd or even?

Comment: @UsmanSaleem to print even numbers only from first column, and print odd numbers from only second column

Comment: OK, not "i" and "j", but first and second column in your array.  Do you want them printed out interleaved or two separate lists?

Comment: (You need to explain things better.  If you can't explain the problem to us, you probably don't understand the problem yourself, so some extra effort put into producing a *clear* explanation will benefit you even if you never hit the "post" button.)

Comment: @Hot Licks It can be separated.

Comment: as there are only two columns in your case, first traverse values of first column and print your desired values, then traverse values of second column and print desired values. If you wish to use only one loop to calculate values, then you would need to declare two more arrays, first one to hold results from first column, second one to hold results from second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab at this but I'm not sure if I quite understand yet.

```
int array[][] = new int[row][col];
// ... populate the array with random numbers, works fine...

// Let's traverse the first column.
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    int value = array[i][0]; // col 0 means first column
    if (value % 2 == 0) {
        // ...
    }
}

// Let's traverse the second column.
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    int value = array[i][1]; // col 1 means second column
    // ...
}
```

Is this what you mean? If it is, do you see the pattern and how you could generalize this and make the code a bit smaller?

Comment: Damn, I think you'r right :) Many thanks! Hmm, smaller.. connect first and second column to one "for"?

Answer (score 0):

Just implement this formula in your "if" statement :

(Number × 2 )/4 ==0. You will always get even numbers. You can handle the rest :D